# Reading SharedPreferences from other activities

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to pass values from one class to another, but my sharedpreferences context probably doesn't work, i got NullPointerExcepiton on line when i initialize shared preferences? What should i change the context to?

CustomOnItemSelected.java :(initializing sharedpref)

```
 public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
            "Wybrano : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("session", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("sessionId", parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
    editor.commit();
}
```

tworzeniekonta.java : (reading sharedpref)

```
       TextView tv6 = findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("session", CustomOnItemSelectedListener.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String sessionId = preferences.getString("sessionId", null);
    tv6.setText(sessionId);
```

Null pointer exception :

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: replace `CustomOnItemSelectedListener.MODE_PRIVATE` with `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` on your other class.

Comment: Still nothing, another NullPointerException at initializing part,  when i start the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you place `SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("session", CustomOnItemSelectedListener.MODE_PRIVATE);`?. Try to call this after activity was created. Preferences should be initialized in onCreate().
Ex:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   TextView tv6 = findViewById(R.id.textView6);
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("session", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      String sessionId = preferences.getString("sessionId", null);
      tv6.setText(sessionId);
   }

}
```

Comment: Works now, i didnt know i had to put it into onCreate and it was in some other method.